# How to navigate thought the errors on NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I've searched this here in this site and others but the answer is CTRL+Period.

I'm using NetBeans ID 8.0.2 and I can't navigate through the errors.

I have a simple class that is giving me error all the time I change some stuff in the classes.
I create some instances of other classes, and every time and I would help me a lot if I just could press some combinations or go to some option to navigate through the errors (something like MS. Word).

Is NB capable of doing that?

PS: In case of having some different answers according the language I'm using... Well I'm using Java

Comment: Compilation error or runtime error?

Comment: -----------
Compilation error

Comment: If you right click on the project and build, it will show a list of errors in the Output window. You can click on the errors to go to the code that is causing problems.

Comment: Beside that, there's no easier way to navigate through errors?